# Where can I put auto-authentication code in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using ReactJS, redux, and react-router. I am using localStorage to log in users automatically. My App.js looks like this:

```
`      <Router>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
              <Route path="/" component={NavBar} />
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/list" component={RoadmapList} />
              <Route path="/roadmap" component={OneRoadmap} />
              <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
              <Route exact path="/add" component={RoadmapAdder} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route
                exact
                path="/savedRoadmaps"
                component={SavedRoadmapsView}
              />
              <Route path="/profile" component={AuthorProfile} />
              <Route exact path="/account/edit" component={Profile} />
            </div>
          </Provider>
        </Router>`
```

I previously did auto-authentication in **my NavBar component** since NavBar will be in every single URL because of the `<Route path="/" component={NavBar}/>`, I thought I could've just used NavBar to auto-login my users using a redux action called loginUser and then update a few redux states like isAuthenticated and user_info. The problem is that if I were to render **NavBar** and let's say SavedRoadmapsView, SavedRoadmapsView wouldn't get the redux states immediately since it runs parallel with **NavBar**.

I have tried to login Users automatically in App.js, like:

```
 `  async componentDidMount() {

    var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
    var userData = { email: email, password: password };
    await loginUser(userData);

  }`
```

It didn't seemed to work. Could it be that loginUser is a redux action and can't be used outside of Provider? What are your insights on this? Thanks in advance.